# MacWire: Found multiple values of type

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.6, macwire

I'm using MacWire DI framework and I'm geting this error.

```
Found multiple values of type [play.api.mvc.DefaultActionBuilder]: [List(defaultActionBuilder, Action)]
[error]   override lazy val controllerComponents: DefaultControllerComponents = wire[DefaultControllerComponents]
```

My applicatopn Loader is this:

```
class AppApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach { cfg =>
      cfg.configure(context.environment)
    }
    new AppComponents(context).application
  }
}

 class AppComponents(context: Context) extends
      BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with AhcWSComponents
      with AssetsComponents with HttpFiltersComponents
      with EvolutionsComponents with DBComponents  with HikariCPComponents  with EhCacheComponents {

      override lazy val controllerComponents: DefaultControllerComponents = wire[DefaultControllerComponents]
```

I've been getting  some other errors similar after small modifications of the  code. How can I follow DI dependencies to track down these errors?

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered this myself, it appears to be due to this commit, which was included as a backport in Play 2.6.3:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/7676/files/809cd1e880b01d45e95d41e65f20bfa984d1e122#r138400765

...so code that compiles with Play 2.6.2 fails with Play 2.6.3.

Workarounds:

- Revert to Play 2.6.2, or...
- ...manually specify the creation of your `DefaultControllerComponents` - ie don't use MacWire for that particular constructor

That's not as pretty, but it works with Play 2.6.3:

```
val defaultControllerComponents = new DefaultControllerComponents(
  defaultActionBuilder,
  playBodyParsers,
  messagesApi,
  langs,
  fileMimeTypes,
  executionContext
)
```